# Convert JRuby DateTime object to Java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: jruby

I am using JRuby Version 1.7.11. I have a requirement of converting a date string in JRuby to a `java.sql.Timestamp`. I am a newbie to JRuby so need some help and how to get this done. Tried like below and I am stuck.

```
require 'date'

datePart = DateTime.parse('2014-04-30')

puts datePart
```

I am not sure how I convert this to a `java.sql.Timestamp` object.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

[A little old, so might have been solved by now - please let us know your findings.]

Your DateTime call gives you a DateTime object.

The java.sql.Timestamp object can be constructed from a explicit year, month, day etc details or via milliseconds argument.

So, you could either do

```
java.sql.Timestamp.new(datePart.year-1900, datePart.month-1,... etc)
```

or

```
# convert to Ruby Time, so that the Java conversion gives you a Java Date object
java.sql.Timestamp.new(datePart.to_time.to_java.time)
```

There might be a way to get from the DateTime object directly to the milliseconds value, but I don't see it.

Cheers.